# How to hide views which contains password information in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, security, sql-view

I have user specific data with in a table. Encrypted some of the columns like password, phone number, address details. Created a view with insert/update triggers on the table. The view takes care of column decryption when it is queried for user data and the triggers take care of encrypting and inserting the values to table.

How can I provide security to the view?

Creating a role and not granting access to the views. Is this the way to provide security? I don't have a clear picture how this is implemented in real time projects. Can anyone please provide some inputs for my better understanding?

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: passwords should be hashed not stored with reversible encryption.

Comment: To store password i will use MD5 hash. To provide security for user data like SSN, account numbers i am trying to encrypt the columns